# transfer files between S3 and EBS with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I move files between amazon s3 and amazon EBS with ruby on rails?

From reading [this article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Ruby/846)
I think it is possible, has anyone seen a good tutorial for how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its one of the simplest thing to do, to make sure I guess your EBS volume is attached to a running aws instance. Try s3cmd or s3fs(fork it only from google projects repo) you will be able to do it.

Comment: turns out it wasnt so easy, if anyone its much easier to get friles from EBS to S3. there is no way to apply NTFS file permissions to S3 files that i could see. :(